# Effiency of pareto distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm working on a pareto distribution, where I have to determine wether the MLE of a Pareto distribution is efficient. I'm a bit stuck now, feel like I been stsaring at it too long a kind of lost the greater picture.

My distribution is $f(x|x_0, \theta) = \theta \cdot x^\theta_0 \cdot x^{-\theta - 1}$

My MLE is $\hat{\theta}= \frac{n}{\sum_i ln(\frac{x_i}{\hat{x}_n})}$

The variance I found to be $I(\theta) = var (\frac{\partial \log f(x|x_0,\theta)}{\partial \theta})$

My idea is to use the following definition from my textbook:

Let $X_1,...X_n$ be independent and identically distributed with probability density function $f(x;\theta)$. Suppose $\hat{\theta_{1n}} = \hat{\theta}_{1n}(X_1,...,X_n)$ is an estimator of $\theta_0$ such that $\sqrt{n} (\hat{\theta}_{1n} - \theta_0) \xrightarrow{D} N(0,\sigma^2_{\hat{\theta}_{1n}}) $. Then the assymptotic variance is defined to be:

$e(\hat{\theta}_{1n}) = \frac{1/I(\theta_0)}{\sigma^2_{\hat{\theta}_{1n}}}$.

It further says, that the estimator $\hat{\theta}_{1n}$ is efficient, if the ratio is 1 of the above expression.

My question is, am I on the right track? And is it just to plug in my variance $I(\theta)$ into  the expression $e(\hat{\theta}_{1n})$?

Comment: Check if it attains the Cramer Rao lower bound

Comment: Which one? And isn't Rao-Cramer an inequality? How does that fit with the estimator is efficient if the ratio = 1?

Comment: Cramer Rao is a lower bound on the variance of an estimator, and if the estimator is unbiased, the bound is equal to the inverse of the Fisher information. An estimator that attains its bound is *efficient*. The ratio you mention being 1 is a statement of (asymptotic) efficiency, namely that the asymptotic variance is the inverse information.

Comment: So actually my first step is to check if it is an unbiased estimator?

Comment: Also, it turns out to be a more general result that MLEs are asymptotically efficient under some regularity conditions.

Comment: Using your definition of (asymptotic) efficiency, you just need to show asymptotic variance of your MLE, $\sigma_{\hat \theta_{1n}}^2$, is the inverse information, as you mentioned.  Sorry for the confusion--I was just relating that to the Cramer Rao lower bound. I think your estimator would be asymptotically unbiased, but in finite samples, MLE may not be unbiased.